# Unable to re install PEAR packages after uninstalling them (Auth & DB)

Tags: php, pear

So I am working in Larry Ullman's PHP 5 Advanced book and Chapter 4 has me using PEAR to install Auth and DB (even though DB package has been deprecated). So I had to pause and do some tutorials on PEAR, because I have never used it before.

In the midst of checking out and testing the install / uninstall commands I came across this error when trying to **re install** Auth, DB and a couple of others:

```
    No releases available for package "pear.php.net/Auth"
    install failed
```

I only get this error with those select few packages. All others I can uninstall and re install all day long. I have tried ever install/uninstall [options] cobination I can come up with, but still receive this message when trying to install. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the cache and then re-installing the package:

```
$ pear clear-cache
$ pear install auth
```